# Volume mount is not happening using Kubernetes plugin in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes

I am using Kubernetes to spin up jenkins slaves on for my builds. I can get the plugin working without any issues.

Now, I am trying to mount a volume using the plugin. After adding the Volumes information in the plugin, its not even starting the container. I am not sure what is missing here.

In Docker file, I have added this line:

> VOLUME /home/myslave

In POD Template(under jenkins configuration) I have these volume configurations:

> Host path:/jenkins/slave
>
> Mount path:/home/myslave

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your Kubernetes has enabled Pod Security Policy? Also any error messages from logs/commands will be helpful.

Comment: Hi Slava, Pod Security is not enabled. Also, there is no specific error in kubernetes. During POD creation, it reaches till the "Started" state. After that its creating another POD and its happening continuously.

Comment: This sounds like the process inside the pod is failing each time and Kubernetes is restarting a pod. Could you check the pod's log?

Comment: That’s the big challenge here. When I try to get the logs, it says “container not found”.

Comment: Can you try using an `emptyDir` first? Make sure everything is working, then swap in the hostpath volume?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response. The issue was due to the UUID of the slave process. I kept the same UUID for all slave process and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 3 actions to fix this issue:

1. rename your container name to `jnlp` in the kubernetes plugin.
2. keep the JNLP configured correctly in your images ENTRYPOINT
3. let "command to run" and arguments to pass to the command empty.